# Reshape data from arrays to table like

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to reshape data sets from array of arrays to table like

original:

```
table_data = [
    ['header_1', 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 99, 100],
    ['header_2', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10],
    ['header_3', 999, 888, 777, 666, 555, 444, 333],
]
```

expected:

```
table_data = [
    ['header_1', 'header_2', 'header_3'],
    [12, 1, 999],
    [23, 2, 888],
    [34, 3, 777],
    [45, 4, 666],
    [56, 5, 555],
    [99, 6, 444],
    [100, 10, 333],
]
```

Comment: `table_data = np.array(table_data).T`

Comment: You mentions pandas and numpy but you demonstrate input and output as a list of lists... Are you using those or purely want to know how to do this with native Python lists?

Comment: @ncfirth or `np.transpose(table_data)`

Comment: even without numpy, if those are regular python lists, I think you could do it in a one-liner:
``[[table_data[0][i], table_data[1][i], table_data[2][i]] for i in range(len(table_data))]``

Comment: @a625993 or `[list(el) for el in zip(*table_data)]`